# Copying vector to std::string

Tags: c++, string, vector, copy

Can anyone explain to me why code below does not work properly ? There is no compiling issues, but output is wrong. I guess problem lies within `std::inserter`.

Program output :

Expected output: 147497

```cpp
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
  std::vector<char> vec;
  vec.push_back(1);
  vec.push_back(4);
  vec.push_back(7);
  vec.push_back(4);
  vec.push_back(9);
  vec.push_back(7);

  std::string test;

  if (!vec.empty())
  {
    std::copy(vec.begin(),vec.end(),std::inserter(test,std::end(test)));
   }
  std::cout << test;
}
```

Comment: `1` is not a char.

Comment: @Quimby It's certainly a valid value for a `char`.

Comment: Those are all ASCII character values that have no standard glyph - what gets displayed (if anything) will depend on how you are running your program. You certainly won't get `147497`

Comment: True, bad phrasing - still will not generate expected output when converted to string.

Comment: Why not `std::string test(vec.begin(), vec.end());`?

Comment: On some systems, you get the funny face characters displayed.  Pretty neat.

Comment: And `vec.push_back('1');` etc. to get your desired output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are inserting non-visual ASCII control characters into your vector.  You need to insert visual ASCII characters instead:

```
// note the use of single quotes!
vec.push_back('1');
vec.push_back('4');
vec.push_back('7');
vec.push_back('4');
vec.push_back('9');
vec.push_back('7');
```

`char(1)` has a numeric value of 1. `char('1')` has a numeric value of 49 in ASCII.

Also, since you are inserting characters into `test` at the end of the string, consider using `std::back_inserter` instead of `std::inserter` (either way, you don't need to test for `vec.empty()` as standard algorithms work fine with iterator ranges where `begin == end`):

```
std::string test;
std::copy(vec.begin(), vec.end(), std::back_inserter(test));
```

Or, just use the `std::string` constructor that takes iterators as input:

```
std::string test(vec.begin(), vec.end());
```